# How was Jesse Pinkman originally supposed to die in season one?

Tags: breaking-bad

I was told that Jesse was originally supposed to die in the 1st season of *Breaking Bad*, but was instead changed to No Doze. How was he supposed to die? Bludgeoned by Tuco, perhaps?

Answer (score 7):

He was supposed to die in a botched drug deal, which would lead to Walt into a guilt trip. You can find more info in this interview with Creator and Executive Producer Vince Gilligan on YouTube: